# Cannot browse new action added to controller in Yii

Tags: gridview, yii2

---

I have created new action **actionupdatestatus** 
but this action does not open in url
and display error

Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request: authors/updatestatus

##

Answer (score 3):

It actually is, for actionUpdateStatus the route would be authors/update-status (notice the extra -)

Comment: and should contain id

Comment: that goes without saying. But the lack of id should have given you another error.

Answer (score 0):

```
404 Error code means page not found.
```

The reason of 404 error code may be your url is incorrect,check the port number and action name(spelling) and also check the action is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if this is Yii2 then mihai is correct.  if this is yii then you probably need to have capitals in your route as some servers are case-sensitive.